# Replace last part of a string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have several pathnames like this:

```
some\cool\path\1\d32a
some\cool\path\2\x3rydf
some\cool\path\3\y42d
some\cool\path\4\qasdf3
some\cool\path\5\jv5
```

I want to replace the last part of the path with `\newPath` on the paths that have 1, 2 or 3 in them (not 4 or 5). Expected result would be:

```
some\cool\path\1\newPath
some\cool\path\2\newPath
some\cool\path\3\newPath
some\cool\path\4\qasdf3
some\cool\path\5\jv5
```

I could do something like this:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET Viewsmap = [method I'm looking for]
WHERE PathName like '%1%'
OR PathName like '%2%'
OR PathName like '%3%'
```

But I have no idea how to change the last part of each string, as it's unknown what the last part of the path will be, and the `Replace` function doesn't seem to accept wildcards.

Comment: One letter at the end for all?

Comment: No, random length of the last part of the path. I will update the question accordingly.

Comment: Expected results?

Comment: Updated the question with expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
LEFT (Viewsmap, LEN(Viewsmap) - CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(Viewsmap)) + 1 )
```

in order to extract the part that is before the *last occurrence* of `\`.

You can then easily `UPDATE`using:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET Viewsmap = CONCAT(LEFT(Viewsmap, LEN(Viewsmap) - CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(Viewsmap)) + 1 ),
                      'newPath')
WHERE PathName like '%1%'
      OR PathName like '%2%'
      OR PathName like '%3%'
```

Comment: The string manipulation is spot on, however, there where is too loose.  Any 1 or any 2 or any 3

Comment: The 1, 2 or 3 is loose, but this is an example, in my real database the second last part (the number in my example) isn't nearly as loose. 

This is the best answer for my purposes, so thanks!

Comment: @ohyeah Understood and agreed.  However I would just simply opt for a more precise match of '%\{somestring}\%'

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `PATINDEX` like this:

```
select 
    case when patindex('%\[123]\%',p) > 0 then 
        substring(p,1,PATINDEX('%\[123]\%',p) + 2) + 'newpath' 
    else p 
    end newP
from t;
```

And in your `UPDATE` command:

```
update mytable
set Viewsmap = substring(PathName, 1, PATINDEX('%\[123]\%',PathName) + 2) + 'newpath'
where patindex('%\[123]\%', PathName) > 0;
```

Comment: Upvoted because I did not know about this functionality yet, so thanks for that!